# where can I find advanced stats questions and answers like the example below?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, example

I am at the beginning of an advanced stats course and I am looking to practice some questions beyond the few which are given in class. below are a few examples from our first assignment. I am looking for books or preferably online resources with questions and answers. Thanks in advance.

In the order in which they are below; to solve you have to use the pmf and CDF of:

Q5 - Poisson
Q2 - Negative Binomial
Q3 - Geometric
Q4 - Hypergeometric

If any interest I can post the solutions shortly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I find that Actuarial Practice Exams for Exam P give a lot of great examples to practice with.

Comment: @RyanHonea Cool example! I would not have thought to google that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about probabilities.

You should consider reading:

> One Thousand Exercises in Probability,
>   Geoffrey Grimmett and David Stirzaker

And who knows, you may even found a pdf version of it on google.